# How to get a inserted id in other table from inside a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 3 tables `tbl_Users`, `tbl_Protocol` and `tbl_ProtocolDetails` and inside of my trigger on `Users`, I have to inserted into `Protocol` and then insert into `ProtocolDetails`, but I don't know how work the inserted scope.

Something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_Users ON tbl_Users 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId     = Int
    DECLARE @ProtocolId = Int
    DECLARE @UserDetail = NVARCHAR(255)

    SELECT 
         @UserId = user_id,
         @UserDetail = user_detail + '@' + user_explanation
    FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO tbl_Protocol (user_id, inserted_date) 
    VALUES (@UserId, GetDate()) 

    -- Return Inserted Id from tbl_Protocol into @ProtocolDetail then

    INSERT INTO tbl_ProtocolDetails (protocol_id, protocol_details) 
    VALUES (@ProtocolId, @UserDetail) 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger has a **MAJOR** flaw in that you seems to expect to always have just a single row in the `Inserted` table - that is **not** the case, since the trigger will be called **once per statement** (not once for each row), so if you insert 20 rows at once, the trigger is called **only once**, and the `Inserted` pseudo table contains 20 rows.

Therefore, code like this:

```
Select  @UserId = user_id,
        @UserDetail = user_detail + '@' + user_explanation
From    INSERTED;
```

will **fail**, since you'll retrieve only **one** (arbitrary) row from the `Inserted` table, and you'll ignore all other rows that might be in `Inserted`.

You need to take that into account when programming your trigger! You have to do this in a proper, **set-based** fashion - not row-by-agonizing-row stlye!

Try this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_Users ON tbl_Users 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    -- declare an internal table variable to hold the inserted "ProtocolId" values
    DECLARE @IdTable TABLE (UserId INT, ProtocolId INT);

    -- insert into the "tbl_Protocol" table from the "Inserted" pseudo table
    -- keep track of the inserted new ID values in the @IdTable
    INSERT INTO tbl_Protocol (user_id, inserted_date) 
        OUTPUT Inserted.user_id, Inserted.ProtocolId INTO @IdTable(UserId, ProtocolId)
        SELECT user_id, SYSDATETIME()
        FROM Inserted;

    -- insert into the "tbl_ProtocolDetails" table from both the @IdTable,
    -- as well as the "Inserted" pseudo table, to get all the necessary values
    INSERT INTO tbl_ProtocolDetails (protocol_id, protocol_details) 
        SELECT 
            t.ProtocolId, 
            i.user_detail + '@' + i.user_explanation
        FROM 
            @IdTable t
        INNER JOIN 
            Inserted i ON i.user_id = t.UserId
END
```

Comment: Thank you for help and the explanation, I didn't know this database has this behavior

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in this trigger that would handle a multiple insert/update statement. You will need to either use one scenario that will handle multiple records or check how many records were effected with a IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1 else statement. In your example, I would just use something like

```
insert into tbl_Protocol(user_id, inserted_date)
select user_id, user_detail + '@' + user_explanation
From    INSERTED;
```

As for your detail table, I see Marc corrected his answer to include the multiple lines and has a simple solution or you can create a second trigger on the tbl_Protocol. Another solution I have used in the past is a temp table for processing when I have very complicated triggers.